# Bash: regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash

Please have a look at this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 =~ a* ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi
```

seems to always print "match" regardless what has been provided as the first argument.
(tested on bash 3.2 and 4.x)

**Question:**
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `a*` means "match zero or more occurrences of the letter a". So if you input `foo`, zero `a`s are matched so the expression is true. If you input `bar`, one `a` is matched so it is also true. Any input you enter will be matched.

Try changing to `a+` if you want to match one or more occurrences of the letter `a`.

```
$ [[ foo =~ a+ ]] && echo match || echo "no match"
no match

$ [[ bar =~ a+ ]] && echo match || echo "no match"
match
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `a+` matches one or more occurrences of the letter "a" *in a row*

Comment: Could just leave off the quantifier entirely since a and a+ are functionally equivalent in this case (testing if at least one a is present)

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing: 
'a*' would match 'a' zero or more times, which matches for pretty much any string. So I'd say you'd have to use 'a+' instead to match 'a' *one or more* times; and also you might want to add '^' or '$' to match at start/end of line depending on what you would like to achieve.

Cheers, Alex

EDIT: Ah, too late again ;-) At least seems like my guess was correct ;-)